# how to serialize() mysql update data

Tags: php

Hi I want to make the serialized reading value 1 or 0 in mysql, how can I do

example code

```
 $query =  $wpdb->get_results('select * from wp_options where option_id = 96');


    $dizi =   unserialize($query[0]->option_value);
     
      // echo $dizi['subscriber']['capabilities']['read'];

       //print_r($dizi);

   if(array_key_exists('read', $dizi['subscriber']['capabilities'])){


       echo $dizi['subscriber']['capabilities']['read'] = 0;
       

   }

   exit;
```

Comment: Do you _need_ to do this through MySQL or can you just use [`add_cap`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_role/add_cap/)? I feel like that would be easier than trying to deal with `$wpdb`.

Comment: You can't do this with a MySQL query, you ***must*** fetch it and deserialize using PHP, make the change, then serialize and save the new serialized value. What exactly are you trying to do that requires this? If you're trying to add or remove a capability to a role there are functions to do that, you don't need to do raw SQL queries, in fact it would be bad practice to do it that way

Comment: ***What are you trying to do that requires this?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use raw SQL to modify roles and capabilities, it is very bad practice, and unnecessary.

Instead, use the roles API, e.g.

```php
$role = get_role( 'subscriber' );
$role->add_cap( 'read' );
```

Or to add it to a specific user:

```php
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->add_cap( 'read' );
```

Likewise you can remove a capability from a role:

```php
$role = get_role( 'subscriber' );
$role->remove_cap( 'read' );
```

Comment: My teacher does not record this, it goes when I deleted the code, I want to register sql

Comment: I do not understand your comment, please rephrase, what do you mean by teacher? These functions use SQL internally

Comment: I want it to be permanent. When add_role () is removed, it goes and the same role is added to every user as long as the code stays there

Comment: So you're using the `WP_User` method? The `get_role` method modifies the database so it should persist/be permanent, that's what the documentation says. How are you testing this?

Comment: sory  I made a mistake id it was wrong                                                                    
                                                                                                                                user = new wp_user(get_current_user_id());
 
    $user->set_role('subscriber');